# response not bringing back data with axios

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

I have a function in php, that returns the `json_encoded` version of a string, but when I `console.log` the response gotten from the json_encoded data in my react app, through axios, the data is usually empty,usually like this,`Object {data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}` ,Please what may be the issue

**PHP FILE**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
return json_encode("works");
```

**React file**

```
import axios from 'axios';
class LoginComponent extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost/login.php')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `return` actually writes tje content to the file?

Comment: Is that your entire PHP file?

Comment: `echo json_encode("works");`

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder, it works

Comment: How about: https://ideone.com/d8XLar